# Error while comparing primitive type inside $watch function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I am trying to understand angularJs watch function better
In order to do so i have made the following bin [enter link description here](http://jsbin.com/huwideduwe/edit?html,js,console,output)
which contains a watch.
THe first time the watch is executed properly an I can see old and new value.
The second time I for both number and string entered in input box I donot see the old and new values logged

```
$scope.$watch(function(theScope){

 console.log(typeof theScope.price ==='number'); //logs true
      if(typeof theScope.price ==='number'){

        return theScope;
      }else{
        return false
      }

    },function(oldValue,newValue){
      console.log('old:'+oldValue);
      console.log('new:'+newValue);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things. If you want to use the function syntax in your watch, write it like this:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);
app.controller('MainController',['$scope',
  function($scope){
    $scope.message =20;
    $scope.$watch(function($scope){
 console.log(typeof $scope.message ==='number');
        return $scope.message;
    },function(oldValue,newValue){
      console.log('old:'+oldValue);
      console.log('new:'+newValue);
    });
  }
]);
```

Also, you were binding to `message` in your html, but you were using `price` in your watch. Also, you were using `theScope`, which wasn't actually used to alias `$scope`.

Paste that code into your bin and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can `$watch` price simply

```
$scope.$watch('price',function(oldValue,newValue){
  if(typeof newValue =='number'){
      console.log('old:'+oldValue);
      console.log('new:'+newValue);
    }
});
```

also change `ng-model='message'` to `ng-model='price'`

[fiddle](http://jsbin.com/fifuleguro/1/edit?html,js,console,output)